# Some Quotes and apostrophes don't parse correctly

Tags: android, xml-parsing

Okay, first, I'm a noob at android programming.  I have taken some Java, but I'm still learning (aren't we all).
I'm trying to take the source code form [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-android/) and have it read an RSS feed correctly.  Currently I have 2 problems.  I'll just state the first one and then post another post for the second.
One the RSS feed is displayed on my device, it doesn't include all of the details (description).  When I load the feed through my browser I notice that some of the quotation marks and apostrophes are turned into " and '.  For some reason this stops the parser from correctly parsing it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the RSS feed that causes problems?

Comment: <description>it&#39;s compact, easy to travel with, fish themed, swings, plays music, and has lights</description>

Comment: here is the RSS feed address :
http://ramstein.bookoo.com/rss.jsp?w=&s=25&n=15&&ck=

Comment: I think that I may have found the problem.  My "characters" function seems to chop up the different portions of the xml document.  This not only happens on the strange characters but on multiple lines as well.  I'm trying to figure out a way to buffer the string until the end of the element.  any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the cause of the problem.  I had to setup a string buffer in the charcters method.

```
public void characters(char ch[] , int start, int length)
{
    if (buffering)
            buf.append(ch, start, length);

}
```

Once I did that, i just assigned the stringbuffer to a string in the "endelement" method when I stored my data.

```
public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException
{

    String content = buf.toString();
    Log.i("RSSReader  ",currentstate +"  " + content + "]");
    switch (currentstate)
    {
        case RSS_TITLE:
                _item.setTitle(content);
                buffering = false;
            currentstate = 0;
            break;
        case RSS_LINK:
                _item.setLink(content);
                buffering = false;
            currentstate = 0;
            break;
        case RSS_DESCRIPTION:
                _item.setDescription(content);
                buffering = false;
            currentstate = 0;
            break;

    }
```

After that everything worked just fine.

Comment: This code is too incomplete to be useful. Please consider adding more to it.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. I used UTF-8 encoding for parsing. But after making it ISO-8859-1, everything went correctly.
I cant paste the complete code but just a sample for you where you can make change is as folows:
My previous code for parsing was

```
Xml.parse(feedStream, Xml.Encoding.UTF_8, root.getContentHandler());
```

After that I converted it as follows:

```
Xml.parse(feedStream, Xml.Encoding.ISO_8859_1, root.getContentHandler());
```

Comment: what would be the code when applied to the sample here http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-android/

Comment: If you check page properly there is "Easier SAX parsing" Under it there is "Listing 7. Android SAX parser" You can find the same code which I gave just replace encoding type.

Comment: I tried that, but no dice.  I noticed that it's a jsp file.  The header says that it's a xml document, but it still has those &#39;s type strings in it.   I'm gonna keep messing around and see what I come up with.

Comment: Then what I suggest is that you write proxy file for that replace such characters.